# ORA-02292: integrity constraint violated - child record found - PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, sql-delete

When I try to delete something from parent table of an application, I get an integrity constraint violated error.

How can i found the referencing table name using query?

Answer (score 4):

If you know the constraint name from the error ORA-02292 message you can find table name referensed to:

```
 select table_name
  from all_constraints c
 where constraint_name = '<constrant name>'
```

Comment: Here table_name mean parent table?

Comment: No, child table. Sorry, I made mistake in where clause, use constraint_name, not r_constraint_name column. When you got error ORA-02292 you can take constraint name from error message and put in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `user_constraints` table as follows:

```
select c.*
 from user_constraints p 
 join user_constraints c on p.constraint_name = c.r_constrainst_name
where p.constraint_type = 'P'
 and p.table_name = '<Your_Table_name>'
```

You can also use `user_cons_columns` in above query to get particular column name of the child table too.